# rospy module init_node fails?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to write a simple python node, but I can't even seem to get rospy imported into my script. Even just the import statement (after running `chmod +x [filename]` ) fails. I'm unable to run the tutorial python nodes as well. What are the possible reasons why this could be happening? I've been able to get a node running just fine on C++.

My (snipped) code, for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

def main():
    rospy.init_node("arm_gui")

main()
```

And the full error text:

```
rosrun SCARA_test_1 random.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mint/Documents/catkin_ws/src/SCARA_test_1/scripts/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 46, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/mint/Documents/catkin_ws/src/SCARA_test_1/scripts/random.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mint/Documents/catkin_ws/src/SCARA_test_1/scripts/random.py", line 30, in main
    rospy.init_node("arm_gui")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init_node'
```

EDIT: Additional system info:

OS: Linux Mint 17.1 (Based on ubuntu 14.04)

ROS: Indigo

PYTHONPATH: `/home/mint/Documents/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212507/rospy-module-init_node-fails?/) by [Vasu Agrawal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22979/vasu-agrawal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-06-30**:
Can you please give some more details about your setup?
What OS/ROS Distro do you have? What does your PYTHONPATH look like?

**Comment by [Vasu Agrawal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22979/vasu-agrawal/) on 2015-06-30**:
Ah, sorry. Edited post with additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've named your script `random`, which overlaps with the system python module of the same name.

When rospy attempts to import random, it instead imports you script, and causes your code to run before the definition of rospy is complete.

You should name your script something else that doesn't overlap with the system python modules.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vasu Agrawal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22979/vasu-agrawal/) on 2015-06-30**:
This seemed to be part of the issue. I was having some trouble after I renamed the file to something else, only to discover that running the other file for some reason ran the .pyc instead (I'd love to know why). However, deleting the .pyc and changing the file name works. Thank you!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-30**:
.pyc files are compiled python byte code; python will treat them the same as their matching .py files, even if those .py files don't exist.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-01**:
great catch, would never have tought of this ;-)